# Entity Framework 5.0 code first one to one and one to many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I have two entities- **Product** and **Picture**. The idea is that a product can have only one picture or none and a picture can be mapped to many products.

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public Picture Picture { get; set; }

    public bool Enabled { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

The **Picture** entity is a mapping to another Pictures entity that contains all of the pictures (this Picture entity contains a mapping only for the pictures for the products), so basically it contains only two columns with Ids.

```
public class Picture
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public int PictureId { get; set; }
}
```

This is my model binder for the **Product** entity

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasOptional<Picture>(pr => pr.Picture);
```

When I create a **Product** entity with picture, or add a picture to an existing entity the **Picture_Id** column that is created in the **Product** table is correctly populated with the **Id** from the **Picture** table. The problem is when I try to retrieve the **Product**. The **Picture** entity inside the **Product** entity is null. I suspect that the mapping is incorrect. Can you tell me how to populate the **Picture** entity inside the **Product** entity when I retrieve it. Here is the retrieval code:

```
 public Product GetProductById(int productId)
    {
        var query = from pr in _productRepository.Table
                    where pr.Id == productId
                    select pr;

        return query.FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

---

**EDIT:** I am using custom **IRepository** service that I include with dependency injection

```
IRepository<Product>
```

The **IRepository** interface contains the following methods:

```
    void Insert(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    IQueryable<T> Table { get; }
```

This is the implementation of **Table**:

```
 public virtual IQueryable<T> Table
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Entities;
        }
    }

    private IDbSet<T> Entities
    {
        get
        {
            if (_entities == null)
                _entities = _context.Set<T>();
            return _entities;
        }
    }
```

I can not add **.Include("Picture")** to the **Table**, because it is **IQueryable**.
I also enabled the Lazy Loading, but there were no result.

Comment: Could you post the code of _productRepository?

Comment: I believe that you have Lazy Loading disabled. See this article, it shows you dofferent ways of loading related data: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896272(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I enabled the Lazy Loading, but there were no effect.

Answer (score 2):

```
var products = db.Pictures.Include("Product");

public Product GetProductById(int productId)
    {
        var query = from pr in products
                    where pr.Id == productId
                    select pr;

        return query.FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you should use include for loading related entities :

```
public Product GetProductById(int productId)
{
    using (var db = new ProductContext())
    {
       var query = from pr in db.Products.Include("Picture")
                   where pr.Id == productId
                   select pr;

        return query.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using a custom repository, so I can not add .Include("Picture") or access the ProductContext in the GetProductById method. Please see the Edit of my post for more info.

Comment: Can I just use join on the Product and Picture tables?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. Not sure if this is the correct way, but it works.

I did the following changes:

```
    public class Product
{
    public int? PictureId { get; set; }

    public int Id {get; set;}

    public Picture Picture { get; set; }

    public bool Enabled { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasOptional<Picture>(pr => pr.Picture).WithMany().HasForeignKey(pr => pr .PictureId);

public Product GetProductById(int productId)
    {
        var query = from pr in _productRepository.Table
                    where pr.Id == productId
                    select pr;

        var product = query.FirstOrDefault();
        AddProductPicture(product);

        return product;
    }

private void AddProductPicture(Product product)
{
    var query = from pic in _pictureRepository.Table
                        where pic.Id == product.PictureId
                        select pic;

            product.Picture = query.FirstOrDefault();
}
```